# Docker compose selenium and java: connection problem

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

I have docker-compose with java project and selenium chrome

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: web:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      args:
        - JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
    depends_on:
      - chrome
    networks:
      - network

  chrome:
    image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium:latest
    shm_size: 2g
    privileged: true
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "5900:5900"
      - "7900:7900"
    networks:
      - network
```

I'm trying to connect to chrome from java

```
        WebDriver webDriver;
        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setBrowserName("chrome");
        dc.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
        try {
            URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
            webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri.toURL(), dc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Couldn't connect WEB_DRIVER");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

This url http://localhost:4444/wd/hub gives me error and this is not because RemoteWebDriver, i have tried different java drivers and got same error

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
 
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132826587Z Host info: host: 'c679ce5cf46d', ip: '172.20.0.6'
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132828628Z Build info: version: '4.5.3', revision: '4b786a1e430'
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132830462Z System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '5.10.124-linuxkit', java.version: '17.0.2'
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132832545Z Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132834462Z Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platformName: LINUX}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platformName: LINUX}}]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132836920Z Capabilities {}
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132839295Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132841253Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132843295Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132845420Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132847462Z  at com.careerseeker.siteparser.service.impl.SiteParserServiceImpl.getDriver(MyServiceImpl.java:222) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132849587Z  ... 25 common frames omitted

2023-03-08T09:01:20.132851962Z Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:4444

2023-03-08T09:01:20.132853920Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:73) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132856087Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42) ~[selenium-http-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132858087Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56) ~[selenium-http-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132873837Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:49) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132876128Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42) ~[selenium-http-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132879337Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56) ~[selenium-http-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132885587Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:99) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132890628Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.TracedHttpClient.execute(TracedHttpClient.java:55) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132892628Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:120) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132894587Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132896545Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132898587Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132900545Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132902503Z  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:541) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.5.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132904503Z  ... 29 common frames omitted

2023-03-08T09:01:20.132906337Z Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:4444

2023-03-08T09:01:20.132908670Z  at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:179) ~[async-http-client-2.12.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132910628Z  at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:108) ~[async-http-client-2.12.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132912628Z  at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28) ~[async-http-client-2.12.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132914712Z  at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20) ~[async-http-client-2.12.3.jar!/:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132917170Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132919128Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132924087Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132929170Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132936920Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132940170Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132942337Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132947003Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132951045Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132953587Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132956045Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132958545Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132960670Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132962795Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132965003Z  at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132970420Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132977003Z  ... 1 common frames omitted

2023-03-08T09:01:20.132979128Z Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:4444

2023-03-08T09:01:20.132981045Z Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

2023-03-08T09:01:20.132982878Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132984753Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132987878Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) ~[na:na]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132992837Z  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132994878Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.132996878Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.133002295Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.133007712Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.133011212Z  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.133014253Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.133020003Z  at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.133022045Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar!/:4.1.85.Final]
2023-03-08T09:01:20.133024212Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I can see that my chrome starts at  http://172.20.0.4:4444

here is some logs from container

```
Starting Selenium Grid Standalone...
2023-03-08T09:00:02.127960717Z Tracing is disabled
2023-03-08T09:00:03.079255718Z 09:00:03.073 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
2023-03-08T09:00:03.082264760Z 09:00:03.081 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
2023-03-08T09:00:04.266523135Z 09:00:04.265 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 5 available processors
2023-03-08T09:00:04.318001468Z 09:00:04.317 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding chrome for {"browserVersion": "110.0","se:noVncPort": 7900,"browserName": "chrome","platformName": "LINUX","se:vncEnabled": true} 1 times
2023-03-08T09:00:04.346006135Z 09:00:04.345 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative
2023-03-08T09:00:04.381115343Z 09:00:04.380 INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching Node 57ecd074-632e-4989-ba29-a9b0e61df39e (uri: http://172.20.0.4:4444) from DOWN to UP
2023-03-08T09:00:04.393940177Z 09:00:04.392 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node 57ecd074-632e-4989-ba29-a9b0e61df39e at http://172.20.0.4:4444. Health check every 120s
2023-03-08T09:00:04.748166885Z 09:00:04.746 INFO [Standalone.execute] - Started Selenium Standalone 4.8.0 (revision 267030adea): http://172.20.0.4:4444
```

and if i use http://172.20.0.4:4444/wd/hub instead of http://localhost:4444/wd/hub for connection, everything is fine with connection.

This message confusing me -> Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:4444(I didn't specify it anywhere 127.0.0.1)

I can specify url like http://172.20.0.4:4444/wd/hub, but i shouldn't, because sometimes chrome starts at different urls. Here is some IPs i saw before when chrome was starting

```
172.20.0.4
172.17.0.3
172.17.0.4
172.18.0.3
172.18.0.4
172.19.0.3
172.19.0.4
```

Connecting via http://localhost:4444/wd/hub only worked when I ran the jar without docker, using a chromedriver file downloaded from the internet, pasting it into the root of the project

---

Please help to connect to chrome container correctly so that the java code does
not depend on different addresses on which chrome is started.

---

Comment: You have url hardcoded in your java code. You should use container name as host if you want to connect from one container to another over common docker network. In your case url should be `http://chrome:4444/wd/hub`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the IP address of the host name `localhost`, and in Docker that almost always refers to the current container only.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have the url to your chrome instance hardcoded in your code and it points to `localhost`.

When container are connected over common network you should use service name as DNS name to connect to it. So in your case url should be `http://chrome:4444/wd/hub` when
connecting from `web` service to `chrome` service.

Comment: But the question owner says: Connecting via http://localhost:4444/wd/hub only worked when I ran the jar without docker, using a chromedriver file downloaded from the internet, pasting it into the root of the project.I relate it because now i have the same error.and using neither : chrome - localhost -selenium-hub seems working